# Template matching program to find an image within an image

Tags: c++, object-oriented

The program I've made is a template matching program which finds an image within an image - where's Wally/Waldo! I've complete the program and all works fine despite being very slow (around a minute). I would appreciate some advice on how I could improve the following code. I'm happy to share the rest of the source code if anyone is interested.

```
        #include "Matrix.h"

    Matrix::Matrix(int sizeR, int sizeC, double val){
    M = sizeR; // Set number of rows.
    N = sizeC; // Set number of cols.
    data = new double[sizeR * sizeC]; 
    }

    Matrix::Matrix(int sizeR, int sizeC, double* inputData){    
    M = sizeR;
    N = sizeC;

    data = new double[sizeR * sizeC]; // Set data sixe
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeR * sizeC; i++) //  input data store
    {
        data[i] = inputData[i];
    }
    }

    Matrix::~Matrix(){
    delete[] data;
    data = 0;
    }

    Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& existingMatrix){
    M = existingMatrix.M;
    N = existingMatrix.N;

    data = new double[M * N]; // Allocate memory
    for (int i = 0; i < M * N; i++) 
    {
        data[i] = existingMatrix.data[i];
    }
    }

         Matrix Matrix::getBlock(int width, int height, int r, int c, int yMove,     int xMove) const{  
    int startCol = r * width;
    int startRow = c * height;
    int cols = width;
    int rows = height;
    Matrix R(rows, cols, 0.0);

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

        for (int ii = 0; ii < cols; ii++) {

            R.setElmt(i, ii, getElmt(i + startRow + yMove, ii + startCol + xMove));
        }
        }return R;
     }

    void Matrix::setBlock(int r, int c, int yMove, int xMove, const Matrix& blockValues){
    int rows = blockValues.M;
    int cols = blockValues.N;
    int startCol = c * blockValues.N;
    int startRow = r * blockValues.M;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) // Rows
    {
        for (int ii = 0; ii < cols; ii++) //Cols
        {
            this->setElmt(i + startRow + yMove, ii + startCol +     xMove, blockValues.getElmt(i, ii));
        }
    }
}

double Matrix::getElmt(int i, int j) const{
    return data[i * N + j];
}

void Matrix::setElmt(int i, int j, double val)
{
    data[i * N + j] = val;
}

int Matrix::getCol() const{
    return N;
}

int Matrix::getRow() const{
    return M;
}

Matrix Matrix::operator-(double value){
    double val = 0;
    Matrix C(M, N, val);

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) // Rows
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) // Cols
        {
            val = data[i * N + j] - value;
            C.setElmt(i, j, val);
        }
    }return C;
}

Matrix Matrix::operator*(const Matrix& B){
    double val = 0;
    Matrix C(M, N, val);

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) // Rows
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) // Cols
        {
            val = data[i * N + j] * B.getElmt(i, j);
            C.setElmt(i, j, val);
        }
    }
    return C;
}

Matrix& Matrix::operator=(const Matrix& B){
    if (this == &B) {
        return *this;
    }
    else {
        delete[] data;

        M = B.getRow();
        N = B.getCol();
        data = new double[M * N];

        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) // Rows
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) // Cols
            {
                setElmt(i, j, B.getElmt(i, j));
            }
        }
    }
}

double Matrix::getSum() const{
    double result = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < M * N; i++) {
        result += data[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226)

Comment: I improved your title. For the future, please read our [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) page

Comment: Does this compile? Your `operator=` doesn't have a return statement after the `else` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code seems very straightforward and easy to read, making it relatively easy to maintain. Here are some ways you could improve it further.

## Naming

I would suggest working a bit on your member variable and local variable names. While in math we often use `M` and `N` as matrix width and height, it can be confusing which is which, and it can be difficult to communicate which you're talking about when speaking because they sound so similar. I would recommend using `width` and `height` as the variable names instead.

Using `i` and `j` for loop counters is a well-understood convention and just fine. I would caution against using `ii` (or `iii` and `iiii` as you had in an earlier version of the code) because it's too easy to confuse it with `i` or make a typo and end up with a subtle bug in your code. (I've done that before!)

## Using `const`

The arguments to almost all of your methods remain unchanged in the method. When that happens, they should be marked as `const` to let a reader know they won't change. It also helps the compiler in a number of ways.

## Performance

You mentioned that it's taking a long time to run. The best way to figure out why is to profile it and see where the slowdown is. I have a guess that it's probably due to the large numbers of copies that the code makes, particularly in `getBlock()`. I can see 2 ways to improve them:

1. Don't make a function-call per element you need to copy. Instead use a block copy function like the standard-C library `memcpy()` function for each row or sub-row you need to copy. This will be much faster than what you're currently doing.
2. Don't copy anything at all. You could modify the `Matrix` class to keep track of the width of a row separate from the number of elements in the row. This would allow you to create a new `Matrix` that just indexed into a current one. You would also need to make sure not to delete the array from that type of matrix, so you'd need another member variable - a `bool` that says whether it owns the array or not. It's slightly more housekeeping, but the result is that your copies now become a pointer assignment and a little bit of housekeeping instead of actual copies. They almost disappear!

Comment: Mant thanks for your advice... I've made some changes based on what you said and I've reduced the computation time by 50%.  thank you.